# MPLAB infinite loop

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mplab

I have 2 questions.

The first: I have  a problem in the behavior of this code; when I run it in Proteus the program make flasher "repeat the code in the main function"
what should I do?

This is the code:

```
#include <p18f452.h>
#include <delays.h>
#include <io.h>

void main ()
{
    TRISC=0x00;
    PORTC=0xff;
    Delay1KTCYx(900);
    PORTC=0x00;
    Delay1KTCYx(900);
    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

The second question: what is the proper delay function I can use? and how can I measure the delay time?

Comment: Your code will flash once only, to fix that move the `PORTC` and delay lines into the body of the loop

Answer (score 2):

Is the watchdog disabled in simulation ? If it is enabled it will cause the repetition of the program.

Try adding this line after the includes.

```
#pragma config WDT = OFF
```

Comment: i did that but the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

You only have code to generate one flash. Move the flash and delays into the loop:

```
for(;;)
{
  PORTC = 0xff;
  Delay1KTCYx(900);
  PORTC = 0x00;
  Delay1KTCYx(900);
}
```

Measuring roughly can be made manually by timing N flashes with a stopwatch. It's of course easier to use a measurement intrument (an oscilloscope is nice for this) if you have it.

Also, since your duty cycle is 50%, you can simplify the code:

```
PORTC = 0;
for (;;)
{
  PORTC = ~PORTC;
  Delay1KTCYx(900);
}
```

This uses bitwise not (~) to invert the bits of `PORTC`, which will make them toggle from one to zero and vice versa. Setting the entire port to 0 before the loop makes sure all pins are at a known state.

Comment: i know this code generate one flash but in the simulation the code generate infinite times of flash

Comment: @GehadMohamed Okay, that sounds strange. Perhaps the simulator resets the simulated machine when it detects the infinite loop, causing the program to restart and generate another flash, and so on. I'm just guessing now, of course.

Comment: Any reason for using `PORTC ^= 0xFF`, rather than `PORTC = ~PORTC`, it just seems a bit less intuitive to me. It's a good idea to write to the `LATx` register rather than `PORTx` register.

Comment: @Colin__s No reason, changed it. Not familiar enough with the PIC18 to introduce other registers, tried to keep it close to the OP's code for ease of understanding. Feel free to edit or post a new answer, of course.